# Hbase data on Slaves

Tags: nosql, hbase

If I use Hbase Cluster, does every slave have the same data or it could be partitioned?
What are the best practices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HBase rows are ordered by the key and automatically arranged into small partitions called regions. Each server handles some of the   automatically partitions the data into regions (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410896/how-hbase-partitions-table-across-regionservers) for more details).
You can let Hbase control the splitting or pre-split yourself to control the load on the cluster

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have ~86 requests per second in picks. Does it make sense to setup Hbase for that?

Comment: Generally speaking hbase can handle this - a regular database + memcached can probably handle that as well. The questions are the data size, how data is queried , update and insert rates etc.