# write data in hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have a problem while write data in hbase.I have 4 region server.when i write data and use radom key ,data write to any region but they are in one region server.One server are busy, three server are free.How do write regularity in all region server.

Comment: Does this explanation help you?

Comment: Please react to questions cldo, and try to take some time writing your sentences.

Answer (score 0):

HBase partitions it's tables across region servers. See :

- [How HBase partitions table across regionservers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410896/how-hbase-partitions-table-across-regionservers)
- http://www.larsgeorge.com/2009/10/hbase-architecture-101-storage.html

I am not sure how random or far apart your random key should be to be able to write to different partitions.

See discussions on `hbase.hregion.max.filesize` and `base.hregion.maxfilesize` which suggests that tables are split to new regions when the appropriate data size has been reached.